# Filtering reverse relationship for a single object in Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

Suppose I have the following two models:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    """
    A person model with the name of the person.
    """
    name = models.CharField()


class Vehicle(models.Model):
    """
    A vehicle model with the owner of the vehicle, and the type of the vehicle.
    A vehicle type could be a car, a truck or a bike.
    """
    owner = Models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='vehicles')
    type = models.CharField()
```

With these two models, Django will automatically create a backwards relation where all vehicles of a person could be accessed by the following query:

```
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
    person.vehicles.all()
```

This will return all vehicles related to that person, so far so good.

Now suppose that I want to get the person object with the vehicles filtered, say I want only vehicles of a bike type. How could I do that?

To put the question in a context, I'm trying to build the following urls:

```
    api.example.com/v1/person/1/vehicles/ [returns all vehicles]
    api.example.com/v1/person/1/vehicles/?type=bike [returns only vehicles of type bike]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
person.vehicles.filter(type='Bike')
```

BTW, It's not that good to use `type` as field name, because it's a python reserved keyword. Try to make it `vehicle_type` instead.

**Edit:**

If you want person objects, do:

```
Person.objects.filter(vehicles__type="Bike")
```

Check django doc about [chaining filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#chaining-filters).

**ReEdit:**

To get a single person's owned bikes, you do:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
all_bikes = person.vehicles.filter(type="Bike")
```

Comment: But how can I return the person object with vehicles filtered, not return the vehicles only? And about the vehicle type, this is not the real model, I'm just trying to make the question simple and clear. Thank you.

Comment: Again this will give me a list of people who owns a bike, but not a single person object with all of the bikes that he owns, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: I edited again my answer.  Check if that makes sense.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you.